# Изменить цвет интерполируемых элементов строки Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Имеется строка, куда я интерполирую (string) строки из переменных. Хотелось бы поменять их цвет, что бы выделить, для большей наглядности.

Comment: изменить цвет string нельзя. Можно изменить цвет текста в uilabel или uitextfield. попробуйте переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Существует строка типа string = "My name : \(name)". Надо изменить цвет интерполируемого текста, то есть name. То есть цвет текста, содержащегося в переменной name.

Comment: Я разобрался как делать используя нижний ответ, но мне придется всю строку переделывать, а она длинная.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам придется использовать [`NSMutableAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring).

И здесь два варианта: либо решать в лоб и использовать конкатенацию, либо ознакомиться с `NSRange` и работать с диапазонами внутри `NSAttributedString`.

Вот пример первого варианта:

```
let prefixString = "Hello "
let infixAttributedString = NSAttributedString(
    string: "playground",
    attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue]
)
let postfixAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "! It's me again!")

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: prefixString)
attributedString.append(infixAttributedString)
attributedString.append(postfixAttributedString)
```

Результат:

[image: NSMutableAttributedString result]

Comment: Собрал я строку из NSMutableAttributedString но!!! я не могу ее добавить (append) к массиву. Из этого массива у меня читает tableView. Если я добавляю string.mutableString as String? то к массиву я могу добавить, но атрибуты (цвет элементов текса) не сохраняется((((((((((

Comment: Ну, разумеется. String и NSMutableAttributedString - это априори разные типы данных, и даункастинг вычистит все атрибуты. Тип потому и содержит в названии слово `Attributed`, что содержит не только последовательность символов, но и атрибуты для них.
Вам нужно создать массив из NSAttributedString, и приводить все строки к этому типу. Если в таблице применяете значения из массива в UILabel, то присваивание нужно делать свойству `attributedText`, а не просто `text`.